# Can I clear chat using a command block?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

In Minecraft 1.9,  <kbd>F3</kbd>  +  <kbd>D</kbd>  will clear your chat.

Because this works, there must be either a command or .class that it calls upon. Can this somehow be run from a command block at a certain period of time?

Answer (score 7):

It is not possible to clear the player's chat using commands.

However, you could dump a large amount of newlines (~100) using `/tellraw`, which will clear their current history but will retain the newlines.

```
/tellraw @a ["\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"]
```

Comment: Will this just look like a bunch of blank lines or will it look like a fresh chat screen? I realized this was an option but I think it'll still give a giant gray box

Comment: @DavidCole-GrammarPolice Unfortunately it will be a giant gray box. There's nothing you can do with commands to get around it, short of requesting the user to clear their chat themselves.